# How to get position of same texts (words) in UITextView

Tags: iphone, ios, uitextview

I am working in a text view. In which I have to highlight same texts in dat particular text view. for example -- in following text of a text view , I have to highlight all 'Apple' word

Development of what was to become the iPhone began in 2004, when Apple started to gather a team of 1000 employees to work on the highly confidential "Project Purple",[27] including Sir Jonathan Ive, the designer behind the iPhone.[28] Apple CEO Steve Jobs steered the original focus away from a tablet, like the iPad, and towards a phone.[29] Apple created the device during a secretive collaboration with AT&T Mobility—Cingular Wireless at the time—at an estimated development cost of US$150 million over thirty months.[30]

I am using this code for finding position of a particular 'Apple' string in dat text view

```
NSString *sel_text = @"Apple";
 NSRange range = [subTextView.text rangeOfString:sel_text];

subTextView.selectedRange =range;

    UITextRange *textRange = [subTextView selectedTextRange];
 CGRect rect = [subTextView firstRectForRange:textRange];
```

this helps me only to find first position of 'Apple' , I am unable to find next position of that string.

so please help me to find all position of that strting

thank you

Comment: Take a look at 'NSRegularExpression'.

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate through the whole string in a simple loop using `rangeOfString:options:range:` selector. For example,

```
NSString *sel_text = @"Apple";
NSRange range = [data rangeOfString:sel_text];
while(range.location != NSNotFound) {

    subTextView.selectedRange =range;
    UITextRange *textRange = [subTextView selectedTextRange];
    CGRect rect = [subTextView firstRectForRange:textRange];

    range = [data rangeOfString:sel_text options:0 range:NSMakeRange(range.location + sel_text.length, data.length - range.location - sel_text.length)];
}
```

Comment: bro in your code at this line.... range = [data rangeOfString:sel_text options:0 range:NSMakeRange(range.location + sel_text.length, data.length - range.location - sel_text.length)];                        I am getting range.location = a garbage value & range.length = 0 , so its not working bro